# Get data from SQLServer in ASC order

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a table with column name id and value. While data is being saved in sql server database, it sorts itself in random order, i.e id value 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,14,15,16,17,8,9,10 and likewise.

I need to retrieve data in 4 groups with each having 11 data in asc id order,

that is,

Group 1: 1-11
Group 2 : 12-22
Group 3 : 23-33
Group 4 : 33-44

I have tried query

Group 1:select top(11) * from tblCode order by id ASC

Group 2:SELECT top(22)* FROM tblCode except select top(11) * from tblCode order by id ASC

Group 3:SELECT top(33)* FROM tblCode except select top(22) * from tblQRCode order by id ASC

group 4:SELECT top(44)* FROM tblCode except select top(33) * from tblCode order by id ASC

What my problem is since data are sorted randomly while saving them into database, they are retrieved randomly.

Below is the screenshot of how my data are saved in database.

[image: Screenshot]
help me select data as above mentioned group.

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: if possible better insert a column 'grp' and put a group name there, then retrieve it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it's SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`OFFSET` and `FETCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned) rather than `TOP`.

E.g. Group two would be:

```
select *
from tblCode
order by id ASC
offset 11 rows
fetch next 11 rows only
```

---

Complete repro script:

```
declare @t table (ID int not null, Value varchar(93) not null);
;With Numbers as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY so1.object_id) as n
    from sys.objects so1,sys.objects so2,sys.objects so3
)
insert into @t (ID,Value)
select n,'PEC-' + CONVERT(varchar(93),n)
from Numbers
where n between 1 and 1000

select *
from @t
order by id ASC
offset 11 rows
fetch next 11 rows only
```

Result:

```
ID          Value
----------- ---------
12          PEC-12
13          PEC-13
14          PEC-14
15          PEC-15
16          PEC-16
17          PEC-17
18          PEC-18
19          PEC-19
20          PEC-20
21          PEC-21
22          PEC-22
```

Comment: @Sdp - I've added a complete repro script that shows it working. If it's not working for you then there's something missing either in the question you've asked or in how you've translated my answer back to your data. I can't do much more given the current level of detail provided by you.

Comment: Yes my database was somehow cleared. 

Thank you, I owe you a beer :)..

Answer (score 0):

This also get your desired results. For other queries change 33 with other values, now it get values from 33 to 22.

```
WITH t AS
( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS row_num, *
    FROM tblCode )
SELECT TOP 11 *
FROM t
WHERE row_num > 33
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select * from Table Name Order by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am not misunderstand:

```
--Group 1
SELECT *
FROM tblCode
WHERE id >= 1
    AND id <= 11
ORDER BY id ASC

--Group 2
SELECT *
FROM tblCode
WHERE id >= 12
    AND id <= 22
ORDER BY id ASC

--Group 3
SELECT *
FROM tblCode
WHERE id >= 23
    AND id <= 33
ORDER BY id ASC
```

You can also save the increments in variable. Maybe something like this (i.e) you send param group no 3:

```
--Group 3
SELECT @Group = 3 --just for sample, param should sent From application 
SELECT @lastIndex =  3*11
SELECT @indexStart = @lastIndex - 10
SELECT *
FROM tblCode
WHERE id >= @indexStart
    AND id <= @lastIndex
ORDER BY id ASC
```